# Ac2git giving Attribute Error

Tags: python, git

I am trying to use ac2git to convert my Accurev Depot to Git Repository. I followed the steps given here: https://github.com/NavicoOS/ac2git. I am getting this error when trying to run the python ac2git.py command and the operation is aborted:

```
2016-08-24 09:07:31,312 - ac2git - ERROR - The script has encountered an exception, aborting!
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ac2git.py", line 3596, in AccuRev2GitMain
rv = state.Start(isRestart=args.restart, isSoftRestart=args.softRestart)
File "ac2git.py", line 2974, in Start
self.RetrieveStreams()
File "ac2git.py", line 1537, in RetrieveStreams
endTr = endTrHist.transactions[0]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'transactions'
```

I used the method as deep-hist and start_tran as 1 and end_tran as "now".
I went through the accurev history and there is a transaction at #1, so what could be the "NoneType" the error is referring to ?

ac2git.config.xml

```
<accurev 
    username="********" 
    password="********" 
    depot="Product" 
    start-transaction="1" 
    end-transaction="now" 
    command-cache-filename="command_cache.sqlite3" >
    <!-- The stream-list is optional. If not given all streams are processed -->
    <!-- The branch-name attribute is also optional for each stream element. If provided it specifies the git branch name to which the stream will be mapped. -->
    <stream-list>
                <stream>Stage1</stream>
    </stream-list>
</accurev>

  <git 
    repo-path="C:\Users\ssrivastava\repository" 
    message-style="notes" 
    message-key="footer" 
    author-is-committer="true" 
    empty-child-stream-action="merge" 
    source-stream-fast-forward="false" > 
    <!-- Optional: You can add remote elements to specify the remotes to which the converted branches will be pushed. The push-url attribute is optional. -->
    <remote name="origin" url="https://github.com/orao/ac2git.git" push-url="https://github.com/orao/ac2git.git" /> 
    <remote name="backup" url="https://github.com/orao/ac2git.git" />
</git>
<method>deep-hist</method>
<merge-strategy>normal</merge-strategy>
<logfile>accurev2git.log</logfile>

<usermaps filename="usermaps.config.xml">
 <map-user><accurev username="******"/><git name="Shruti Srivastava" email="******" timezone="+0500"/></map-user>
</usermaps>
</accurev2git>
```

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? (Props for migrating to a good VCS)

Comment: I was using the version 3.4.3.

Comment: I think you should post here the config file and the arguments passed to the utiltiy

Comment: Added the config file.

Comment: My guess is that you have a typo on your stream list. You could just try to leave it empty and it will process all the streams

Comment: @Av4t4r you were right, there was a typo with the name of the depot and I also reverted to the Python version 3.4. Can you answer the question so that I can mark it as approved.

Comment: Added. Great to hear you can now leave the painful world of AccuRev behind!

Comment: I've raised an [issue](https://github.com/NavicoOS/ac2git/issues/75) against the repository to provide a more sensible error message for this type of error in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, looks like you had a typo in your stream/depo name